# How to detect user successfully share the post after post_id get deprecated

Tags: facebook

FB documentation states i have access to the to the post_id until October 12 2016 by using feed method, but till now i still can have the post_id after successfully shared the post, my question is this post_id really gonna get deprecated, if so, how can i verify user have been successfully shared the post after deprecation. We have some promotion going on, need to detect whether the user have shared the post or not. Thanks in advance!

**Edit**:
Our promotion page is a static page, we don't require user to login to our application.

```
The parameter post_id is in a 6 month deprecation window for use without publish_actions permission. Beginning October 12, 2016, post_id requires your app to have publish_actions granted, and for the user to share to their timeline or a group.
```

Comment: what for do you need to know exactly? does the user HAVE to share something?

Comment: btw, without user authorization there is no way to get the post id, even without deprecation. but my questions are very important for a good answer.

Comment: _"my question is this post_id really gonna get deprecated"_ - that's not what that message says. The conditions under which you will be able to get the post id back after a successful share using the Feed dialog change. But if you want to use it to reward the user for sharing in any way, shape or form - forget it, that is not allowed.